# libsodium + windows 10 x64 + Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, libsodium

I'm struggling with getting Kalium wrapper for libsodium to work in Eclipse.
My first attempt was not to use Maven. So I downloaded Kalium's Jar, downloaded x64 DLL of libsodium added it to win32 folder.

Result? no luck: I got an error from the libsodium wrapper that it is unable to load a library.

So I decided to go the official way... I didnt want to as it required maven which I wasn't using.
so I installed maven. added Kalium to dependancied; installed Maven plugin for Eclipse.

now when I try to compile my projekt which loads Kalium lib. I get very similar error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.loadNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:87)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getNativeLibraries(NativeLibrary.java:70)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.getSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:49)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibrary.findSymbolAddress(NativeLibrary.java:59)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.generateInterfaceImpl(AsmLibraryLoader.java:117)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.AsmLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(AsmLibraryLoader.java:59)
    at jnr.ffi.provider.jffi.NativeLibraryLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibraryLoader.java:43)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:290)
    at jnr.ffi.LibraryLoader.load(LibraryLoader.java:269)
    at org.abstractj.kalium.NaCl$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(NaCl.java:41)
    at org.abstractj.kalium.NaCl.sodium(NaCl.java:28)
    at org.abstractj.kalium.keys.KeyPair.<init>(KeyPair.java:36)
```

is there libsodium-dev for windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: 
rename libsodium.dll to sodium.dll and copy to C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\