# Using Libsodium/Kalium in a java project

Tags: java, libsodium

I'm trying to encrypt passwords using the Libsodium library using Kalium as a Java warpper. I'm trying to install it but I'm running in a few issues. I have added the Kalium dependency to my pom.xml and placed the libsoidum in my javapath as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552364/libsodium-windows-10-x64-eclipse). Now i actually want to use the library to hash my passwords en start saving them in my database. (I know oAuth is preferred but that's not an option in the software.) The problem is I have no idea how to actually use the wrapper. I can't find any documentation or examples. Is there a source out there that can help me?

Comment: Why that library specifically?

Comment: @Tim I am now using the windows x64 .dll. I have to find some way to port it to heroku (possibly using another library) since in the end the application will be deployed there.

Comment: That's not what I meant; You say you want to encrypt passwords with Java; What's in `libsodium` that you want to use that's not available in the hundreds of other encryption libraries more easily integrated with Java?

Comment: @Tim Ah I see. Well I went looking for ways to hash passwords. The most  articles/posts/explanations I read all pointed me towards Libsodium. So that's why I wanted to use it. If you have another recommendation that works great that would be fine too.

Comment: It appears libsodium uses argon2, which is also available in other Java libraries. Otherwise bcrypt is well supported across languages.

Comment: @Tim I see, thanks for the info. I will look into those options.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import com.muquit.libsodiumjna.SodiumLibrary;
import com.muquit.libsodiumjna.exceptions.SodiumLibraryException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Encrypt2 {


private static String libraryPath = "D:/libsodium/libsodium.dll";

private static String ourPassPhrase = "your very secret password";
private static byte[] passPhrase = ourPassPhrase.getBytes();
private static String ourMessage = "password which you want to encrypt and decrypt";
private static byte[] privateKey = (ourMessage.getBytes());


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    SodiumLibrary.setLibraryPath(libraryPath);
    encrypt();
    decrypt();
}

private static void encrypt() throws SodiumLibraryException {

    System.out.println("----Encrypt-----");

    // The salt (probably) can be stored along with the encrypted data
    byte[] salt = SodiumLibrary.randomBytes(SodiumLibrary.cryptoPwhashSaltBytes());
    byte[] key = SodiumLibrary.cryptoPwhashArgon2i(passPhrase, salt);

    String saltedPrivateKey = new String(key, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("saltedPrivateKey bytes - " + saltedPrivateKey);
    /**
     * nonce must be 24 bytes length, so we put int 24 to randomBytes method
     * **/
    byte[] nonce = SodiumLibrary.randomBytes(24);
    byte[] encryptedPrivateKey = SodiumLibrary.cryptoSecretBoxEasy(privateKey, nonce, key);
    String encryptedPW = new String(encryptedPrivateKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("encryptedPrivateKey bytes  - " + encryptedPW);
}

private static void decrypt() throws SodiumLibraryException {

    System.out.println("----Decrypt-----");

    byte[] salt = SodiumLibrary.randomBytes(SodiumLibrary.cryptoPwhashSaltBytes());
    byte[] key = SodiumLibrary.cryptoPwhashArgon2i(passPhrase, salt);
    byte[] nonce = SodiumLibrary.randomBytes(24);
    byte[] encryptedPrivateKey = SodiumLibrary.cryptoSecretBoxEasy(privateKey, nonce, key);
    privateKey = SodiumLibrary.cryptoSecretBoxOpenEasy(encryptedPrivateKey, nonce, key);

    String dencryptedPW = new String(privateKey, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println("our secret phrase - " + dencryptedPW);

    }
}
```