# Add Libsodium JNI to a java project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-native-interface, libsodium

I would simply like to be able to use the libsodium JNI binding of the libsodium C library in my java project on Eclipse. I'm on Windows x64, and the libsodium JNI documentation isn't very detailed about importing to a Java IDE. I imported and compiled the C library libsodium on Visual Studio, but I don't really know what to do with the generated dlls. I don't even know if I should use a jar on Eclipse, or even import the c files... I also read about Maven but that didn't get me much further. If someone can come to my rescue I would be very grateful since I don't understand anything lol.

I tried to generate a jar with Maven, and to import it on Eclipse but I cannot initialize the library with "NaCl.sodium();". I logically have errors because I advance a little blind. I also tried importing the C files and linking the DLL library to the JAR library, but that didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [libsodium + windows 10 x64 + Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552364/libsodium-windows-10-x64-eclipse)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.